# Google API PHP Client - how to disable event reminders?

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using [Google API PHP Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), to manage my Google Calendar in a web app.

It appears the reminders set through Google Calendar, get re-send by the API class. So I get 2 different notification emails for the same reminder. One is from Google itself, the other is a very simplified plain-text from the API class (I think). The sender from the 2nd one is the email address registered with the Calendar API app.

How do I disable these extra email notifications from the API class?

**Edit:** Removing the reminder via Google Calendar, also disables the extra reminder from the API class. So it's linked, obviously.

Comment: Are you setting any reminders programmatically? If so, how are you doing it? I just created an event using that library (with no reminders) and only got the reminder that I have previously configured on Google Calender (and which is sent for every event).

Comment: @ViniciusPinto I haven't touched any reminder settings from the library itself. For some reason I automatically receive a 2nd reminder (simple, one line plain-text) from the email my web app is registered with the Google API.